# If I want to use std::shared_ptr, which header to include?

Tags: c++, header, c++11, shared-ptr

In c++0x shared_ptr will be moved from tr1 into std. So which header to include to get it?

I am using g++ 4.5 (ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: @James That question is nothing but a rant. How you decided to write so good answer? ;)

Comment: Just always search for your symbol on cppreference.com to be 100% sure.
See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll find it in `<memory>` now.

Comment: If you want cross-platform compatibility (I can vouch for OS X) you might need to prefix it with `<tr1/memory>` for now; and that should remain valid.

Answer (score 2):

1. headfile is memory;
2. It's defined in namespace std;
3. You need specify -std=c++0x